# Update multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update views on multiple components. For that reason I am using broadcast. If I use my code without the $apply() the views are not updating. If I use apply on multiple views I am getting '[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress' error.

Changed code

```
service.prototype.setNewTopic = function (topic) {
    var self = this;
    var promise = $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: self.baseUrl + 'Admin/setNewTopic',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            topicName: topic
        }
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish from this snippet, but it *looks like* you are trying to broadcast and have each component get data in response to the broadcast.  This seems inefficient, but the data definitely should be updating without the use of `$scope.$apply()`.  This **feels like** an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  You should ask about why your data isn't updating in the first place, rather than why `$scope.$apply()` isn't working.  In other words, show your component and it's view in a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you. If this seams inefficient, could you please point me to more efficient way

Comment: not without seeing an example of *what you are actually trying to do*, no.

Comment: I added above my service as well. I am trying to broadcast and update views after new Topic is added.

Comment: Ok, correct me if I am wrong here? You have multiple controllers which use same service and you want to change their views (models) by this same service. Right?

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's what I wont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to how your $on method behaves, it should recive the data from the $broadcast and I guess set it appropriately in the component.

// controller - I assume the $scope property in the controller is called $scope.newTopic

```
 service.setNewTopic($scope.newTopic).then( function(data) {
      $rootScope.$emit('testMonitor',$scope.newTopic)
   })
```

// one of these per listening component

```
$rootScope.$on('testMonitor', function(data) {
  $scope.newTopic = data;
});
```

I changed the service to only do http work
// service

```
service.prototype.setNewTopic = function (topic) {

    return $http(
    {
        method: 'POST',
        url: self.baseUrl + 'Admin/setNewTopic',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            topicName: topic
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I need it. Shall I use it the same way even in the controller where I am actually setting the topic. Or I need to create a separate HTTP for this. Or maybe I should return the promise and then broadcast it.

Comment: I think the controller should call your service.setNewTopic(topic). Personally I think the controller should handle the broadcast, service.setNewTopic().then( function(data){  $rootScope.$emit( 'testmonitor' , data) } ). Which means the service should just do the http call, only... I would also change it from $rootScope.$broadcast('testMonitor')  to $rootScope.$emit('testMonitor') as this is a less expensive call to make

Comment: Thank you. I thought that in the data that I am broadcasting is the json object, but I have 'Success'. I am trying to parse it like :self.newTopic =  $.parseJSON(data); . And I got and error that the json is not correct. Hot can I set the data in the view? How to set the data in your changed code in the controller?

Comment: I understand, that means your POST call doesn't return your data but rather a SUCCESS/fail, this means you should broadcast your newTopic instead, i.e $scope.newTopic... do you mean to say you also have problems sending the POST? Updating the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to combine setting the topic with getting, but I got 404 error. Do you have any idea why. I changed the code above

Comment: but setting a topic sounds like a POST operation on your backend API. if your backend expects this to be a POST, self.baseUrl + 'Admin/setNewTopic'  then 404 is a logical error cause the route is not set up to be a GET,   if you change your call to a GET the backend needs to change with it..     can you change the backend though?